# Why is return value optimization happening here

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization

From [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) post it states

> When a nameless temporary, not bound to any references, would be moved
>   or copied into an object of the same cv-unqualified type, the
>   copy/move is omitted. When that temporary is constructed, it is
>   constructed directly in the storage where it would otherwise be moved
>   or copied to. When the nameless temporary is the argument of a return
>   statement, this variant of copy elision is known as RVO, "return value
>   optimization".

So in order to test that concept i tried the following experiment

```
class C
{
    public:
        C()
        {
            std::cout << "Constructor of C." << std::endl;
        }
        C(const C &)
        {
            std::cout << "Copy-constructor of C." << std::endl;
        }
};

C func()
{
    const C c;
    return c; //c is not a nameless and is not CV unqualified as it is a const type. 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    C c = func();
}
```

Output : 
Constrcutor of C

I was expecting:
Constructor of C
Copy-Constructor of C
Copy-Constructor of C

My question is why is return value optimization happening here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you've quoted an irrelevant paragraph. The relevant one is the one above (from the same source):

> If a function returns a class type by value, and the return statement's expression is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, which isn't the function parameter, or a catch clause parameter, and which has the same cv-unqualified type as the return type of the function, then copy/move is omitted.

*Any* of the stated conditions permit copy elision.

Comment: That still doesnt answer it. The return type is a constant so its not cv-unqualified and also the return type is not a temporary. it was created in the function and then returned.

Comment: @MistyD: The return type is not constant. The object you are returning is. But either way, it's irrelevant. The text is not saying that it needs to be cv-unqualified. It is saying that the type of the returned object (with cv qualifiers removed) needs to be the same as the return type of the function (with cv qualifiers removed).